# certificate common name `*.c.ssl.fastly.net' doesn't match requested host name

Tags: linux, ssl

I'm using Linux do download something. I use get "wget" command. But I got this error:

```
[root@vps server]# wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/x/xlrd/xlrd-0.9.3.tar.gz
--2014-05-10 11:24:40--  https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/x/xlrd/xlrd-0.9.3.tar.gz
Resolving pypi.python.org... 103.245.222.175
Connecting to pypi.python.org|103.245.222.175|:443... connected.
ERROR: certificate common name `*.c.ssl.fastly.net' doesn't match requested host name `pypi.python.org'.
To connect to pypi.python.org insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: Have you considered reading error message and following its advice? Note that network/CDN management issues are generally off-topic on SO. At very least explain if you need to fix server (should post on http://serverfault.com instead) OR which way to fix client code.

Comment: Please don't follow any stupid advice of a program which is not able to do certificate validation right.

Comment: This worked for me
"echo check-certificate = no >> ~/.wgetrc"
Answer from https://drupal.org/node/2041223

Comment: @CoderTong, you should never put this in to `~/.wgetrc`: **all the connections you'd then make with `wget` would be vulnerable to MITM attacks**.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like the wget version you use attempts to verify the host name only against the common name of the certificate, but fails to check against subject alternative names, which contain `*.python.org` and thus match the host name. It looks like you need at least wget version 1.12. 
For similar reports google for `wget subject alternative name`.

BTW, even if some program suggests you to just switch of certificate verification like wget does in this case, you have to ask yourself if this is the right way to solve the problem. Usually it is not and there is a lot of code out there which causes problems because the authors just did the easy thing and switched off certificate verification. This includes banking applications etc. HTTPS without certificate verification is practically worthless.